# Creating a bot in Xcode 6 OS X server 4 - Repository Credentials issue

Tags: xcode, osx-yosemite, osx-server

Environment details:

Client: Macbook pro, OSX 10.10  Xcode 6.1
Server: Macbook pro,  OSX 10.10, OSX Server 4 with Xcode 6.1

I am currently attempting to set up a CI server automated build
process for our project, and keep hitting a recurring problem. Every
time I try to create the build automation bot in Xcode, I encounter
the "Provide repository credentials for this bot" dialog .Regardless of the
credentials entered (https or ssh), the creation of the bot seems to
fail as it cannot access the repository to clone the required source.

I have tried both SSH and https access:

In the case of https access, I am using my bitbucket username and
password (I have admin access level on the repository) - so far this
has never worked

In the case of SSH access I have already added the SSH key being used
to connect to the Deployment keys setting of the required repository.
This worked only once after many many attempts, pulling the source
onto the server and attempting a build. It failed again however on the
first subsequent commit to the repository and has not worked since
(still challenging for credentials)

Have also tested with a couple of other (test) repositories, both of
which worked fine with both https and SSH access to create and
schedule bots. One of these was a repo created in my own account, the
second was a shared repo (as is the one I am having the issue with).

Any suggestions on other things to check would be welcomed :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently trying to set up a CI environment using Xcode Bots, too, and run into the exact same problems.

When i create a Bot from the account that the server runs under, it works if the SSH-keys are configured in my remote repository (gitlab).

However when i try to create a bot from another machine using the log-in mechanism into OS X Server, it constantly asks me for credential information again, no matter what i enter -.-
Also tried HTTPS instead of SSH...

The problem seems to be the difference in private/public-keys for SSH (Server does not have the matching private key for the public-key you supply when you create the bot/repository).

Trying to find a good solution for this as i cannot copy all the private keys from our developers to the OS X Server account, any advice? Getting HTTPS to work would be best i guess...